# Hide action/more button in form view in odoo12

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

I want to hide only action/more button not print button in odoo12. I found some similar question its not working in odoo12.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a decent answer, but a direction for you.
In source code(my version is 11) 
*odoo-11.0/addons/web/static/src/js/chrome/sidebar.js* L#34

```js
    init: function (parent, options) {
        this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        this.options = _.defaults(options || {}, {
            'editable': true
        });
        this.env = options.env;
        this.sections = options.sections || [
            {name: 'print', label: _t('Print')},
            /* disable this line
            {name: 'other', label: _t('Action')},
            */
        ];
```

This can  remove action button not only in form view, but also include list view.

Or in *odoo-11.0/addons/web/static/src/xml/base.xml* L#326

```xml
<t t-name="Sidebar">
    <t t-foreach="widget.sections" t-as="section">
        <div class="btn-group o_dropdown">
            <button t-if="section.name != 'buttons'" class="o_dropdown_toggler_btn btn btn-sm dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <t t-if="section.name == 'files'" t-raw="widget.items[section.name].length || ''"/>
                <t t-esc="section.label"/> <span class="caret"/>
            </button>
```

Maybe you can consider to attach some if-condition for removing action button in form view from these file.

Comment: you can also use browser's developer tool to set break-point in `sidebar.js` L#34 to check difference of variables between form view and list view.

Comment: maybe it can help you to find correct setting in if-condition.

Comment: Just found out `options.env.context.params.view_type` can detect  where you are.

Comment: `var view_type =this.env.context.params.view_type;
if (view_type == 'list'){ remain code L# 33,34}` add this in `sidebar.js`