# Hiding or disabling Action dropdown button in form view in odoo 10

Tags: button, odoo

just wondering if it's possible to disable or hide the action dropdown menu in odoo 10
[image: this image]

how can I disable or hide it thank you

Comment: Do you want to hide it completely?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hide action/more button in form view in odoo12](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56889201/hide-action-more-button-in-form-view-in-odoo12)

Comment: You may have to adapt the answer to Odoo 10

Comment: I already tried that it didn't work

Comment: can anyone teach me how to use that code, I think it only work in odoo 11-12 my odoo version is 10 do I need to modify it?

Answer (score 0):

found the answer [here](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-remove-hide-the-delete-function-inside-the-more-button-by-role-group-131052) guess I only need to add the "delete" attribute in the  tag